# Counter variable as the step value of for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

In Java, we can change the counter variable of a for loop inside its header itself. See below:

```
for(int i=1; i<1024; i*=2){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I know the following code is wrong. But is there a way to write like that without changing `i` value inside the loop. I like to make my for loop simple and short :-)

```
for i in range(1, 1024, i*=2):        
    print(i)
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun The step is multiplicative not additive

Comment: @MosesKoledoye My bad. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, you could use `for i in (2**k for k in range(10))`

Comment: **You could try this**

**Python 2.x**

**Integer**

    for i in xrange(0,10,2):
      print(i)

**Float:**

    for i in xrange(0.0,10.0,0.2):
      print(i)

**Python 3.x**
**Integer:**


    for i in range(0,10,2):
      print(i)

**Float:**

    for i in range(0.0,10.0,0.2):
      print(i)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own generator to do that for you:

```
def powers_of_two(start, end):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start *= 2

for i in powers_of_two(1, 1024):
    print(i)
```

which gives:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
```

Comment: That makes the code more complex. But hopefully, it does what I expected. :-) Thanks.